# How do i generate a random number but make sure its between a range of two numbers (JAVA)

Tags: random, generator

I need to generate a random number between 8 and 32. then multiply to the power of 2. then repeat it in a loop 10 times. I can't figure how to generate the number within a range this is what i have so far.

```
 function btnGenerate_onclick()
{
// assign textbox elements to variables for easier access
var outputTextbox = document.getElementById("txtOutput");


for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
System.out.println(Math.pow(2, Math.floor(Math.random() * 32 + 1); ));
}


outputTextbox.value = ;
```

}

Comment: I updated my answer to be in javascript.  I missed that you were working in js until I saw your new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain english:

Math.random returns a number between 0 and 1.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp

Multiply that by the range between the numbers `number2-number1` to get a number that is between `0` and greatest `range-1`.  We can call it `range`.

Add the lower bound number `number1` to get a number that is between `number1` and `number2`

Here is the program in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/gXSxTl03BFTFDMVFd0YC?p=preview

```
var random = Math.random();

var number1 = 5.0;
var number2 = 12;

var range = number2-number1;
var rangedRandom = range*random;

var rangedRandomPlusLeast = number1+rangedRandom;

var rangedRandomPlusLeastAsInteger = Math.round(rangedRandomPlusLeast);
```

Answer (score 2):

Following code generates random number between 50 and 100 (Both inclusive).

```
final int MAX = 100;
final int MIN = 50;
.
.
.
Random r = new Random();
// nextInt is normally exclusive of the MAX value,
// so add 1 to make it inclusive
int randomNumber = r.nextInt((MAX-MIN) + 1) + MIN;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` gives a number between 0.0 and 1.0. If you multiply it by 32, you get a number between 0.0 and 32.0. If you want something between 8 and 32, you should do `Math.random() * 24 + 8`. That will give you something between 8.0 and 32.0.